# Alias for repeatable Swagger/OpeanAPI meta-annotation

Tags: annotations, swagger, openapi, spring-annotations

I have a REST controller, in which each method is bearing Swagger's `@ApiResponse`annotation for multiple response codes. In case of an HTTP 200 response code the schema implementation differs for each endpoint method, but for all the other response codes the implementation is the same.

Is it possible to create an alias only for the implementation in the HTTP 200 case?